# Can I be paid from two businesses?

Tags: salary

I work for two completely different businesses that share the same office space. The owners of the businesses are married and I am their office manager.

When they first hired me, they told me that neither business was busy enough to warrant a full-time person. We agreed that I would be paid four hours of each day from each business. I am, and always have been responsible for, all the duties and responsibilities that transpire during an eight hour workday, for each business.

I have worked for them for a few years now, and they have built upon both businesses. To be honest, I now feel like I am working two very busy full-time jobs for the price of one. I am so overwhelmed I am considering changing jobs. I need advice. Is it legal to get paid from two businesses at the same time?

Comment: You don't say what country you are in, but in the US it certainly is.

Comment: It's certainly legal in the US to have multiple jobs.... I'm not sure what you're really trying to ask or accomplish here. If they ate overloading you or not paying you enough, you need to take thst up with them or go job-hunting; there is probably no legal remedy hete (and trying to invoke one would probably result in your being let go anyway).

Comment: Please clarify what you're actually asking. Are you wondering about being paid by two seemingly separate entities, or are you asking how to cope with working full-time for two related businesses, or are you really asking about what to do about compensation for the way you're working?

Comment: How many hours are you working?   If you have to work more than 8 hours then just bill appropriately or refuse to work more than 8 hours.

Comment: You need a raise for sure. But one advantage you have, is job security. You are rooted in like a Mississippi blue tick. Of course, everyone is replaceable, but If you leave, at this point, they would need to hire two people.

Comment: @OverWorked: It's legal in the USA and many other countries, but **not** in some countries - particularly India. See http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/relieving-letter

Comment: "I now feel like I am working two very busy full-time jobs for the price of one" - You said in your description you agreed to work 4 hours on each role/office/business. Is that still the case, or have the hours increased over time and maybe that is the real issue?

Answer (score 8):

## Let them know you're unhappy

This situation came from a different climate for both businesses and as time has changed, so have your expectations. You sound like you've done very well in your role(s) and you would like to grow as an employee - you should talk to them and give them a chance to make things right. Let them know you're unhappy and try to present some changes that would benefit both parties.

That doesn't mean you can't leave later anyway but you should give your employer some understanding of how you are feeling about the whole situation so they will have an opportunity to make it right.

## In future - talk with both businesses

You asked if it's legal to work for two businesses at once and unfortunately there isn't a generic answer to this one, not even by locale. Whenever you're faced with this situation you need to chat to both companies to work out how they want to structure this. Ideally, from a tax and benefits perspective you would be best suited (in most countries) by receiving your pay by one business and having one reporting line.

Answer (score 2):

While it is perfectly legal for an individual to work two jobs it is not legal for a company to "work the system" in order to not have an FTE employee and they still have to offer benefits (ACA).

This is a very muddy situation where proof would have to be provided on either side to show a definitive line in the work you do and that you aren't just truly a FTE. This is a hot item that courts are dealing with now since ACA.  See below direct from IRS:

> "Employer Aggregation Rules Companies with a common owner or that are
>   otherwise related under certain rules of section 414 of the Internal
>   Revenue Code are generally combined and treated as a single employer
>   for determining ALE status.  If the combined number of full-time
>   employees and full-time-equivalent employees for the group is large
>   enough to meet the definition of an ALE, then each employer in the
>   group (called an ALE member) is part of an ALE and is subject to the
>   employer shared responsibility provisions, even if separately the
>   employer would not be an ALE. Example 3 – Employers are Aggregated to
>   Determine ALE Status: Corporation X owns 100 percent of all classes of
>   stock of Corporation Y and Corporation Z.  Corporation X has no
>   employees at any time in 2015. • For every calendar month in 2015,
>   Corporation Y has 40 full-time employees and Corporation Z has 60
>   full-time employees. Neither Corporation Y nor Corporation Z has any
>   full-time equivalent employees.  Corporations X, Y, and Z are
>   considered a controlled group of corporations. Because Corporations X,
>   Y and Z have a combined total of 100 full-time employees for each
>   month during 2015, Corporations X, Y, and Z together are an ALE for
>   2016.  Corporation Y and Z are each an ALE member for 2016.  Corporation X is not an ALE member for 2016 because it does not have
>   any employees during 2015."

Comment: Note that this is an international forum so posting US standings isn't of great benefit

Comment: It could certainly of value... but should be flagged as a US-specific answer.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere As user43748 says though, this is a very muddy situation in that both companies share the same office space and are jointly owned. He's right in pointing out that this is a potentially tricky legal situation and while I would say it's unlikely that the owners set this up to avoid a FTE, it's certainly possible.

Comment: @Codingo It's a safe bet that English speaking OPs who don't specify a location are located in the US and given the situation a country-specific answer is fine.

Comment: @Lilienthal I stand corrected, happy to concede on this. Appreciate the insight!

Answer (score 0):

The legality of it is irrelevant (and off topic), you want a change.  While reporting both employers and having them go out of business/to jail (assuming the behavior is illegal) or being fired as a trouble maker (assuming that the behavior is legal), will result in a change, it'd be easier and more efficient to just quit.

It sounds like the heart of the issue is that your responsibilities/work load has increased to such an extent that it is now difficult or impossible to meet the demands.  The solution is to talk to both employers about making changes so that you are once again able to do what needs to be done on an ongoing basis.

The most obvious change is a promotion/new employee -- add a new employee to help with the workload. If that is not possible, how about shifting some of the workload to the employers?

If you can't reduce the workload, you may have no choice but to make a more drastic change.  I would look elsewhere and then quit once a new position was found, instead of going to a lawyer/the police.